# Why I can't use getFullYear() or any other function when I attach toLocaleString() with a variable?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, reactjs

```
let new_date = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: 'Asia/Qatar', timeStyle: "medium", hourCycle: "h12" });

console.log(new_date.getFullYear())
```

Comment: Calling `.toLocaleString()` results in a **string**; the `new_date` value is not a Date instance.

Answer (score 3):

The reason is that `toLocaleString` returns a `string`, not a date, see [Date.toLocaleString() return value](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/toLocaleString#return_value)

```js
let new_date = new Date().toLocaleString("en-US", { timeZone: 'Asia/Qatar', timeStyle: "medium", hourCycle: "h12" });

console.log('new_date type:', typeof new_date)
```

If you use a date / time library such as [luxon](https://moment.github.io/luxon/#/), you can create a DateTime object in the desired zone. This has a `.year` property which will give you the full year:

```js
let { DateTime } = luxon;

console.log("Time:", DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date(), { zone: 'Asia/Qatar'}).toISO())
console.log("Year:", DateTime.fromJSDate(new Date(), { zone: 'Asia/Qatar'}).year)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/luxon/2.0.1/luxon.min.js" integrity="sha512-bI2nHaBnCCpELzO7o0RB58ULEQuWW9HRXP/qyxg/u6WakLJb6wz0nVR9dy0bdKKGo0qOBa3s8v9FGv54Mbp3aA==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
```